# Splint screen into 3 in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

As mentioned in the title , I'm having problem with splitting screen into 3 parts using Libgdx. I'm trying to make a card game with 3 areas: board, player's cards and menu. While looking for the solution in SO i found out that i should use Stage for each part of the screen and change viewport with setScreenBounds func. However it doesnt work as expected. Here is my code :

```
public void create(){
        board = new Stage();
        userCards = new Stage();

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(board);

        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));

        TextButton asd = new TextButton("asd", skin);
        TextButton asd2 = new TextButton("asd", skin);

        Table tab = new Table();
        Table tab2 = new Table();

        tab.setFillParent(true);
        tab2.setFillParent(true);

        tab.debug();
        tab2.debug();

        board.addActor(tab);

        userCards.addActor(tab2);

        tab.addActor(asd);
        tab2.addActor(asd2);

        board.getViewport().setScreenBounds(0, 0, 960, 270);
        userCards.getViewport().setScreenBounds(0, 270, 960, 270);

    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);       

          userCards.getViewport().apply();
          userCards.act(delta); 
          userCards.draw();

          board.getViewport().apply();
          board.act(delta);  
          board.draw();   


    }
```

As u can see I'm testing it on 960x540 window size. Screen is splitted as i wanted to ( into 2 parts ) however buttons don't look normal ( their height is scaled down). What am I doing wrong? Also, how can i set input processor for all stages? Calling Gdx.input.setInputProcessor() sets it only for last called stage. Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
So my code looks like this now :

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen{
    Skin skin;
    Stage board;
    Stage userCards;    
    Game g;
    Viewport viewportB, viewportUC;

    public GameScreen(Game g){
        create();
        this.g=g;
    }

    public GameScreen(){
        create();
    }
    public void create(){
        board = new Stage();
        userCards = new Stage();

        InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();

        inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(board);
        inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(userCards);


        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);


        viewportB = new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 540/3*2);
        board.setViewport(viewportB);

        viewportUC = new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 540/3);
        userCards.setViewport(viewportUC);

        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));

        TextButton asd = new TextButton("asd", skin);
        TextButton asd2 = new TextButton("asd", skin);


        Table tab = new Table();
        Table tab2 = new Table();

        tab.setFillParent(true);
        tab2.setFillParent(true);

        tab.debug();
        tab2.debug();

        board.addActor(tab);

        userCards.addActor(tab2);

        tab.addActor(asd);      
        tab2.addActor(asd2);

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);       

         viewportUC.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),  Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3); //set the currentWindow... variables in the resize method to keep proper ratio
          userCards.act(delta); 
          userCards.draw();

         viewportB.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3*2);
          board.act(delta);  
          board.draw();   


    }
```

Dunno if it is important however i didn't change resize metod at all ( is blank ). My output : [windowImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49dGR.png)

Size of buttons seems ok now but its position isn't i guess or i'm missing something. Do you know how to fix this?

**UPDATE 2**
Code looks like this now : http://pastebin.com/e5K8Y2fN. Problems : tables aren't centered on stages + adding elements to table doesnt work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you observe is about **stretching the graphics** due to characteristics of default Stage viewport which is type of **ScalingViewport**. You have to create your own **ExtendViewport** which actually does not scale anything and set it bounds to one third of screen then set it to the stage.

```
    //in the show() method
    viewport = new ExtendViewport(SCREEN_WIDTH, Runner.SCREEN_HEIGHT/3);
    stage.setViewport( viewport );

    //in the render method
    viewport.update(currentWindowWidth, currentWindowHeight/3); //set the currentWindow... variables in the resize method to keep proper ratio
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
```

You can read [more about viewports here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)

---

To set more than one inputProcessor you should use [InputMultiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html) instance

```
    InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();

    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage1);
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage2);
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage3);
    ...

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```

### ----------

UPDATE

Two things that you are missing are

- **centering camera position** - that's why stages are on on the center but somwhere on the right
- **setting viewports position** - after camera centering you will observe that one of the stage overlaps second so you need to move the first over the second which will do split actually

The example code to achieve this:

```
    ExtendViewport viewport1, viewport2;
    Stage stage1 = new Stage(), stage2 = new Stage();

    @Override
    public void show() 
    {
        viewport1 = new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3*2); 
        stage1.setViewport(viewport1);  

        viewport2 = new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);        
        stage2.setViewport(viewport2); 

        //... adding actors etc     
    }


    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //here you are centering camera
        viewport2.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3, true); 
        stage2.act(delta); 
        stage2.draw(); 

        //here you are centering camera
        viewport1.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3*2, true);

        //here you are positioning the viewport on the screen
        viewport1.setScreenY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);
        viewport1.apply(true);

        stage1.act(delta); 
        stage1.draw();         
    }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work or ( as always ) i'm doing someting wrong:
`viewportB = new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3*2);
board.setViewport(viewportB);  
viewportUC = new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);
  userCards.setViewport(viewportUC);
public void render(float delta) {
viewportUC.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),  Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);
userCards.act(delta); 
userCards.draw();
   
viewportB.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3*2);
board.act(delta);  
board.draw();     
 }
`
Can u help me with this ?

Comment: I'm testing your code and I see problem with stages position on screen (both are bottom) but no stretching - is this your problem now? BTW please update the question or use some external service like pastebin or whatever to share your code in comment... :)

Comment: Done and sorry for my previous comment, didn't know how to put code there and wasn't sure if users are noticed about editing / updating posts so that they know if theres something new.

Comment: np - imho best is to edit post and write an information in a comment :) Ok I see we have similar output give me a minute to check it

Comment: check out my update - you were missing camera centering and stage's viewport position setting

Comment: Thanks! Now it works great ! I suppose with 3 stages i should do same things right ? Also, be ready for more questions about libgdx because i think ill have more problems with it . One more time : dzięki ! :P

Comment: Glad to help :) Yup I guess that three stages won't make a difference - it should work also. If the answer is fitting your question you can accept it as proper - [read here more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: My happiness wasn't long. With those settings i can't center table. Before i could do it with : `tab.setFillParent(true);` however it doesnt work after splitting. Any ideas whats wrong now ?

Comment: I don't think that it was changing anything here - check for errors somewhere else I guess - [look at this picture](http://i.imgur.com/ZlZwt6v.jpg) - I've tested it with my code, also check for Table instance not Image - but they are the same in this case to be honest

Comment: It seems that not. i mean i have just tried with buttons and it works well just like in your test. With only one stage ( and default setting for viewport ) fillParent for table works good also( table is in the center ). But with that splitting it doesnt.Also adding more than one element to the table ( button in this case ) doesnt work ( after adding 3 buttons i can see only one). This is what i get after fillParent(true) [link] (http://imgur.com/3dbsGin) . It means i cant use tables with that viewport changes ?

Comment: Share the code od screen class it's hard to diagnose without seeing this

Comment: you are using `tab2.addActor(asd2);` to add elements which I suppose is Group-class-like adding actors and that's why the elements overlaying each others due to having the same position. To add actor to Table in a **new cell** you should use **add()** method instead so for example: `tab2.add(asd2);`